Autorizacion a Controller en forma Dinamica
¿Alguien ha trabajado con Autorize basado en roles de identitycore de manera profunda ?
No quiero usar de forma estática por ejemplo
[Authorize(Roles="Admin,Manager")]
public class ClientsController : Controller
{

}

Lo cual funciona, pero si digamos se crece la aplicación y de hecho por eso precisamente se tiene un create Roles, me parece que es más esfuerzo estar actualizando el back con el código estático
En vez de estático busco algo que sea dinámico, es decir que por cada rol se pueda determinar el nivel de acceso a los controladores
Por decir que desde una vista donde se tengan todos los roles, se escoja un rol cualquiera y si por ejemplo elijes Rol Admin le pueda seleccionar todos los controllers a los cuales tiene o tendría acceso
En esa medida hacer dinámico el [Authorize]
¿alguien sabe cómo lograr esto o usa solución similar para lograr este cometido?

Puedes utilizar policy y claim, puedes tener muchas policy y cada una de ellas puede contar con muchas claim. Basicamente responde a una forma versatil de agrupación, por lo que que colocar dependerá de tu caso de uso.
Por ejemplo, tú dices que los controladores son asignados dinámicamente a los roles, entonces una idea puede ser agregar una policy por cada controller con una sola claim
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Clients", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Clients"));
    options.AddPolicy("Boletas", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Boletas"));
    //etc
});

Y luego en tu contoller agregas:
[Authorize(policy: "Clients")]
public class ClientsController : Controller
{

}

Finalmente, cuando el usuario de autentifica debes agregar las claim que le corresponden según los controllers que tiene acceso

Muchas Gracias! Con esto Solucione. saludos
